# How to handle ARRAY_LITERAL with multiple QUERY()'s when one of them returns no value in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the formula below, which works when all of the `query()` functions return data.
How to handle the error, in case one of the returns nothing?

```
={
  query({A3:F},"select * where Col1 is not null");
  query({H3:M},"select * where Col1 is not null");
  query({O3:T},"select * where Col1 is not null");
  query({V3:AC},"select Col1, Col2, Col7, Col8, Col5, Col6 where Col1 is not null")
}
```

Comment: Why not you are using one `QUERY()` function. I think you do not need many query.

Comment: Hello @Harun24hr! I need to combine these ranges vertically. I'd be interested in knowing a different approach. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Ok. IFERROR() may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
={ IFERROR(QUERY({A3:F11},"select * where Col1 is not null"),{"","","","","",""}); 
   IFERROR(QUERY({H3:M11},"select * where Col1 is not null"),{"","","","","",""}); 
   IFERROR(QUERY({O3:T11},"select * where Col1 is not null"),{"","","","","",""}) }
```

DO adjust ranges to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap everything in one QUERY, that won't leave empty spaces nor give an error:

```
=query({A3:F;H3:M;O3:T;V3:W,AB3:AC,Z3:AA},"select * Where Col1 is not null")
```